# grid view for uiviews

Tags: ios, gridview

I have about 30 views in my app and via navigationBar I can move from first to the lust one and back.

1. I want to add a button in a NavigationBar that will popup a gridview with previews of all the views to let user choose any view and move to the chosen one.
2. I also want to let user change the sequence of the views inside that gridview. And let the user mark some of the views as unseen in order to take them away from original sequence of views but not from the gridview.
3. Also let user change gridview to 2x2, 3x3 or 4x4.

What is the best way to make it possible?

Thank you beforehand.
Sorry for my English...

Answer (score 1):

You want UICollectionView with a grid layout.  See http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-uicollectionview-tutorial/ for an example implementation.

Comment: Thank you, I thought about using this variant. But the example tells about using the array of images. I have a list of viewControllers. Do you know how to insert these views inside UICollectionView?

Comment: Ok, I'll try to load the preview images of my viewControllers. The question is how to move to the sertain viewController when taped on the preview from the gridview... I don't need it to be loaded modally. If you know the right way plese feel free to share)

Comment: You shouldn't use view controllers for a grid of items, probably. I'd do it all with views. You could create a delegate protocol for your views to communicate back to the view controller (the way a table cell calls didSelectRowAtIndexPath on its delegate).